# query about Hard drive for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive

Im using a ddr 2 mother board, is SATA 3.0 GBPS will be compatible.
I know this is out of ubuntu but please answer

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't be. Why don't you boot a live USB to test?

Comment: This is completely off-topic. Your mainboard manufacturer can answer your question. Make and model of motherboard are usually found printed on the motherboard itself. Take a peek and download the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDR2 RAM was released in 2003, and SATA Revision 2 (3.0Gbps speeds) was released in April 2004. There is a good chance it will be supported since they are technologies released around the same time, but it depends on your motherboard specifically. If you can find the model of your motherboard or computer, you can do a quick google search to find its specifications and whether it supports SATA Revision 2 (3.0Gbps). Also, if it doesn't support that speed your hard disk will still work as the SATA hard disks are backward compatible. It just won't be as fast.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu should run fine. If you are unsure, simply put the desktop installer disk on a usb key and boot from it. It'll let you know if it can't install itself to your computer.